# React toggle class in map fuction for one item(but when another will be put remove from anothers)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It turns out the filter for the calendar is done through the map and there are 7 objects how to make it so that when choosing holidays there only holidays got the class active and when you clicked on another filter another object became active and everyone else lost the asset class? Is there an example of what? I always have that all at once active then only the first click (

```
   {
_.map(this.firstRowEventTypes(), (item, key) =>
    <button className="event-type-item" onClick={() => this.filterEvents(item.color)} key={key}>
    <div className="event-type-circle" style={{backgroundColor: item.color}}/>
    <div onClick={ () => this.setState({active: this.state.active === item.color ? null : item.color}) }
className={classnames("event-type-name", this.state.active === item.color && 'calendar-filter-active')}>{item.name}</div>
</button>
    )  
}  

filterEvents(color) {
    const events = [];

    this.state.allEvents.map((val) => {
        if (val.color === color) {
            events.push(val);
        }
    });

    this.setState({...this.state, events});
}
firstRowEventTypes() {
        return [
            {color: '#108aeb', name: 'Заседания', id: '1'},
            {color: '#4caf50', name: 'Обучение', id: '2'},
            {color: '#87cefa', name: 'Праздники', id: '3'},
            {color: '#ff5252', name: 'Корпоративы', id: '4'},
            {color: '#ab47bc', name: 'Спорт', id: '5'},
            {color: '#e91e63', name: 'Культура', id: '6'},
            //color: '#8d6e63', name: 'Другое'},
            {color: '#d1d1d6', name: 'Другое', id: '7'},
            //{color: '#108AEB', name: 'Корпоративный'},
            //{color: '#87cefa', name: 'Гос. праздники'},
            //{color: '#e91e63', name: 'Корп. мероприятия'},
            //{color: '#8d6e63', name: 'Корп. развитие'},
            //{color: '#ffa726', name: 'Спортивный'},
        ];
    }
```

[This is items from map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3btu.png)
when i put button all items toggle new class(
how to toggle active class for one item when i put button( and remove from another?

Answer (score 1):

You can set array index `key` or `item.id` to state as active button

```
{
    _.map(this.firstRowEventTypes(), (item, key) =>
        <button className="event-type-item" onClick={() => this.filterEvents(item.color)} key={key}>
            <div className="event-type-circle" style={{backgroundColor: item.color}}/>

            <div onClick={ () => this.setState({active: item.id}) }
                 className={classnames("event-type-name", this.state.active === item.id && 'calendar-filter-active')}>{item.name}</div>
        </button>
    )
}
```

Comment: sorry( it doesn't work for me( too give for all class or do not give to all (active:true or active:false)

Comment: You cannot determine which element is active by one boolean only. This is simply not possible. In order to say which element is active, you need to save its identifier, as aserov said. Alternatively, you can have a boolean per element. But this means that each one must have its own state, which means it has to be its own react component. You choose.

Comment: I changed id to color ( i didnt have id i array) but it doesnt help it is work for first click but when i clicked second time nothing changed(

Comment: In you case is that possible two button has active class or there must be only one?

Comment: Do i need to do for all item private remove and toggle class event?

Comment: I have map = seven Items and i need when clicked put one button this button toggle class and another butt remove active class

Comment: change `onClick={ () => this.setState({active: item.color}) }` to `onClick={ () => this.setState({active: this.state.active === item.color ? null : item.color}) }` if you want remove active second click on same button